# Calculate Q parameter for Deep Q-Learning applied to videogames

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am working on Deep Q-learning applied to Snake, and I am confused on the methodology. Based on the DeepMind paper on the topic and other sources, the Q-value with the Bellman equation needs to be calculated as follows:

```
Q(s,a) = r + γ(max(Q(s',a'))
```

While calculating the Q-value for Q-table is straightforward, it's not clear to me the process in Deep Q-learning. According to some sources, the future possible states for the actual state need to be processed with Deep Learning and the highest Q-value needs to be chosen (input: future state, output: Q-value, or input: current state, output: Q-value for future states). Then, a table containing `[state, action, reward, future_state]` is stored in memory to reduce *critical forgetting*. I don't understand how we get the Q-values to predict in first place, if we need the states in order to compute the Q-values. Is this approach correct, or I am missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: This part "Since my four parameters do not have the same length . . . the neural network returns an error." seems like you are doing something wrong unrelated to your problems understanding Q learning. A neural network accepts a vector of parameters - what exactly are you doing that returns an error - it reads amost as if you are doing `NN(state)` then `NN(new_state)` then `NN(action)` then `NN(reward)` i.e. trying to run the network four times with four very different inputs?

Comment: I am doing `NN(state, action, reward, new_state)`, and in practice `NN( [True,False,..] , 1 , -10 , [False, False,...])`. I don't fully understand how I can create the training set in this format in order to predict Q, without having Q that I would need as target.

Comment: I don't understand in that case why you are getting an error - the NN should work fine with those inputs. They are the *wrong* inputs for solving Q learning, but you should not be getting an error. However, there's not much point trying to show you the right Q learning approach if you are not able to make a working NN in the first place. You should maybe ask a different question about that first, so it can be resolved. Otherwise any advice here still won't work, because your NN won't work . . .

Comment: Could you please explain me why they are the wrong inputs? I'm going to fix the net, but first I'd like to understand what I am doing wrong, it's my first reinforcement learning project. Thank you

Comment: You need to fix your understanding of neural networks first, or attempt a simpler Q-learning project without neural networks. Trying to do both on the same project at once whilst you are still learning both will be too hard. As an answerer I don't want to answer half your project, since you won't be able to make it work with it half solved (so you won't know if my answer is useful or not to you). Scale back, try something less ambitious.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The fact that the network is not working might depend on the wrong format of the data. I have experience in deep learning for computer vision, and "basic" Q-learning is already clear to me. I started this specific project because studying Deep Q-learning is not enough to grasp it and I need an actual application to understand it fully.

Comment: The neural network is *probably* not working because you don't understand how to handle concatenated data from multiple sources. Your computer vision experience does not seem to be enough for you to understand that. If you asked a separate question about that, and removed references to your NN not working from this question, it would be answerable.

Comment: You are totally right, I asked on stackoverflow about handling such data in a neural network. I edited this question in order to reflect more the theoretical part behind DQN, and not the specific example of my neural network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neural network you need to implement for Q-learning must approximate the Q function $Q(s,a)$. There are two ways to do this:

- Using $(s,a)$ as input. A lot of the literature will assume this for simplicity, and you will see notations like $\hat{q}(s,a,\theta)$ to show you are approximating the function, and have parameters $\theta$ to learn for the neural network.
- Using $(s)$ as input, and have the network output multiple $Q(s,a)$ values - one for each possible action. E.g. if you have four possible actions, then your output might be $[\hat{q}_0, \hat{q}_1, \hat{q}_2, \hat{q}_3]$. This can be more efficient, since in order to find the best, maximising, action, you need all the action values calculated.

Once you have a neural network set up like this, and a table of history (that grows on each action actually taken), this is how you make use of it:

```
For each sampled [state, action, reward, future_state]:
  Calculate td_target = reward + gamma * max_a'(Q(future_state, a')):
    Run NN(future_state, a') forward for each possible action a' and find max
  Train the NN using the inputs (state, action) and desired output td_target
```

You would use this variant if the network output multiple Q values at once:

```
For each sampled [state, action, reward, future_state]:
  Calculate td_target = reward + gamma * max_a'(Q(future_state, a')):
    Run the NN(future_state) forward and take the max output
  Construct the desired output:
    Run the NN(state) forward to get array e.g. [q0, q1, q2, q3]
    Substitute td_target depending on action e.g. [q0, q1, td_target, q3]
  Train the NN using the inputs (state) to learn the desired output
```

Although this second approach looks more complex, it avoids looping (or mini-batching) over multiple `a'` values to find a max, so can be more efficient.

If you are using a frozen copy of NN to help with stability (a common feature in DQN), then you should use the frozen copy exclusively to calculate TD targets, and the learning copy to calculate current outputs.

Note it is important that you don't store, but instead re-calculate Q values  at all times. That is both because the initial values will be incorrect (depending on how the NN was initialised), and also that they should improve over time as the agent learns a better policy.

Another important detail is that you should not use the NN to calculate Q value for terminal states. If `future_state` is terminal, then instead of using the NN, treat `max_a'(Q(future_state, a'))` as zero. Typically just detect that this is a terminal state and hard-code a `0` somehow for it.

Comment: Thank you for your very exhaustive answer and your patience. If I understand this correctly, `NN(future state, a')` is going to have, for example, three different future states related to three different actions. I need to approximate the three of them and consider the highest value. This is what confuses me: in order to run my NN I need a trained model with (s,a) and a correspondent Q. But until I run my NN, I don't have a Q-value.

Comment: @MauroComi: That's exactly right. The initial estimates for Q will be strongly biased (towards whatever your random initialisation outputs). Over time and many iterations this bias should reduce, because the value for *reward* is real data. Also, if there are terminal states $s_T$, then it is strictly true that $\text{max}_{a'} Q(s_T, a')$ is zero, and that is again real data being fed in to the algorithm and providing solid foundations to eventually learn from.

Comment: (+1) - By `td`, do you always mean *temporal difference*? I've not yet delved too deep into TD Learning; is there a clear distinction between Q-Learning with and without TD in the context of a time-series problem, such as video game frames? Do you have any literature recommendations other than [Sutton/Barto](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html)'s awesome book?

Comment: @n1k31t4 Q-learning *is* a temporal difference method. TD is the idea of using the Bellman equations to relate the value between time steps so that the estimate for an earlier time step can be updated based on the estimate from a later time step. To avoid it completely in value-based RL, you would use Monte Carlo control. You can also compromise between TD single-step and Monte Carlo approaches by using n-step approaches or eligibility traces.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thank you, as I thought. This means that, after having a value for TD(state, action), I need to store that value which is a prediction of my Q-value, so that the dataset to iteratively train the NN is composed by <state, action, td-target> - the td_target will be progressively less biased. I do not store the Q-value predicted for future states since they don't consider the contribution of the _real data_ (reward).

Comment: @MauroComi: Don't store Q values in the history table (except very temporarily in local variables to do calculations). All the predictions change over time. If you mean store them as updatable estimates in a tabular Q table, then yes that is necessary if you are not using a neural network. The NN is a substitute for this Q table.

Comment: I mean, store different combinations of states, actions and predicted Q-value in a dataframe everytime I calculate one in order to train the NN. Maybe, when I encounter the same state and same action, I need to update the Q-value in the dataframe that I will use to train the NN, while when I encounter a new combination of state - action I need to store it as it is? Otherwise I wouldn't know which values I need to pass to train the NN.

Comment: @MauroComi: No, don't store the Q value in that way. You *must* recalculate it every time. I already say that in this answer. It is important. If this was a tabular version, the same thing applies: You would look up the current value in the $Q(s,a)$ estimates table, not use the target value from last time.

Comment: Exactly, I need to recalculate it every time. In order to recalculate it, I need to 1) know the values of Q(s',a') for the possible actions, values that 2) I predict with a NN trained on _something_. This _something_ is data stored somehow containing state, actions and related output (q-value?). Am I right? Sorry for bugging you so much with my doubts

Comment: That *something* for part 2  (calculating the TD target) is whatever `future_state` value you have and that is all. Absolutely don't use stored Q values. I show this in my answer `Run NN(future_state, a') forward for each possible action a' and find max` - no reference to any historic action or Q value in that.

Comment: @NeilSlater Great, so a case might be: Initially train a NN with `state=1, action=1, td_target=1`. Then run the game, and the values I have are: `state=2, possible current action = 2 (takes to future state 3, with future possible actions = 5 and 6), possible current action = 3 (takes to future state 4, with possible actions 7,8)`. I fit my NN with Q(3,5), Q(3,6) with the net based on the initial NN(1,1), get the maximum between them and calculate Q(2,2). Temporarily store to do the same for the other possible action Q(2,3), and train the NN with the 2 new computed values. Then repeat.

Comment: @MauroComi: That looks correct. The initial training does not need to be specially coded, you can start with no training on the very first steps. However, most of the steps will of course be dependent on the training that has happened so far, so it does work in practice how you describe.